# What is inter-lane skew insertion in display port

Tags: display, port

I am reading the display port specification facing some issue in understanding some terminology
1. What is inter lane clock skew
2. In the  fig 2.8 what is bus steering ?

Comment: Oh yeah that old figure 2.8 conundrum.

Answer (score 1):

In Displayport, the video data stream is transmitted over multiple lanes.

Bus Steering is the block that splits the single data stream into multiple lanes at the transmitter side and combines multiple lanes into single data stream.

Inter lane clock skew means the difference of the reception time of symbols. The skew can be due to one lane being longer or shorter than another one so the symbol is received later or earlier. However, in Displayport, there is also intentional skew between the lanes, where the transmitted symbols are delayed on purpose.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot